# Running Worksheet Event from a subroutine

Tags: excel, vba

I only want the following worksheet event to run when a button is clicked. Is there a way to deactivate and activate a worksheet event from another subroutine?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
  Cancel = False
  Target.Font.Color = vbRed
End Sub
```

Comment: You can call that event manually if you want, but you cannot deactivate it. That has to be done in the routine itself, by setting `Cancel = True`

Comment: If you set a flag (global variable etc) from the button you can have the event check the flag and exit if set.

Answer (score 0):

`Application.EnableEvents = False` can be placed anywhere in the project and will suspend all events until the property is set back to True, possibly in another procedure. True is the default which will be set when you load Excel.